# when a sentence starts with words 'As stated by the law'

Tags: legalese, adverbial-phrases

Is it acceptable in English grammar, when a sentence starts with such words like:

> As stated by the law No , in the process of registration.... one should
>
> As provided by the chapter No ..of the Code of Ethics, you are required to...
>
> As prescribed by the intercompany rules and regulations, the entities should

I am interested to know whether the rules of English grammar allow for putting non-principal parts *directly after* a comma rather than principal parts (the grammatical subject and the predicate) like in my first example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The longer you delay the subject in a sentence the more clumsy the sentence can become, but that's a matter of style rather than grammar.

As you can see in this rather rambling sentence, which I  thought of as I was reading the question you posted 25 minutes before I started my response, **I wrote** 28 words in five clauses before I arrived at the subject and verb of the main clauses
.

Comment: Funny ). However, I've instantly understood your rambling sentence. Thanks. Ok, that is a matter of style.